# How to display specific digit in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below

```
   month
0    1
1    2
2    3
3   10 
4   11
```

for example,I would like to display this dataframe in 2 digit like this

```
     month
0     01
1     02
2     03
3     10
4     11
```

I tried many method but didn't work well. How can I get this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
print (df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2))
0    01
1    02
2    03
3    10
4    11
Name: month, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd still pick @jezrael's answer over this, but I like this answer too

```
df.month.apply('{:02d}'.format)

0    01
1    02
2    03
3    10
4    11
Name: month, dtype: object
```